# Hide div under some table cells but not another ?

Tags: css, overlay

In this example

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="top">
       1 <div id="overlay"></div>
    </td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="top">5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="top">9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="top">13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
td {
width:50px;
height:50px;
background:#aaa;
}
#overlay {
top:100px;
left:30px;
background:#0a0;
width:100px;
height:100px;
position:absolute;
z-index:0;
}

.top{
background:#333;
z-index:100; 
}
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/4dfppb7k/

The overlay move dynamically with the mouse.

How can I  make the overlay div goes under the first column ( cells : 1,5,9,13) but over the rest of the table cells ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `position`(`position: relative`) the `td`s(1, 5, 9, 13) for the `z-index` to work.

Also, you could use `tr td:first-child` to avoid using the `.top` class.

```css
td {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #aaa;
}
#overlay {
  top: 100px;
  left: 30px;
  background: #0a0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}
tr td:first-child {
  background: #333;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      1
      <div id="overlay"></div>
    </td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>11</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>15</td>
    <td>16</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

`z-index` only works on element which are positioned.  If you add `position: relative` to your `top` class, your `z-index` will have the desired effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/4dfppb7k/1/

```
.top{
    position: relative;
    background:#333;
    z-index:100; 
}
```